# Backbone set without merge

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

It seems that backbone merges fields when they are added to model using `set` method. Is there any way to add new fields without merge - replace existing object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) doesn't support a direct replacement of the properties, but you can use [`Model.clear`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear) to achieve what you want, something like:

```
var m = new Backbone.Model({a: 1, b:2});
console.log(m.toJSON());

m.clear({silent: true});
m.set({c: 3});
console.log(m.toJSON());
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hsjnhmeb/